# Is "as well as" a preposition here or conjunction?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions, parts-of-speech

A short passage [from a book](https://books.google.com/books?id=V26MAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA169&dq=%22kind%20of%20person%20that%20he%20is%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj65oD-8aj_AhU5PkQIHScrBWAQ6AF6BAg0EAI) piqued my interest:

> Nevertheless, it is this third line of argument which offers the most hope, by bringing
> us into a largely unexplored area of moral philosophy which has close connections with
> the idea of seriousness discussed earlier. **As well as** questions of the form ‘What
> ought one (anyone) to do?’ or ‘What is the right thing to do?’, which may **seem tacitly to**
> assume that individuals are infinitely flexible, there are also questions of a different kind
> about what some particular individual ought to do, being the kind of person that he is;
> and we do not answer these questions if we say simply that he ought not to be that sort of
> person.

I guess my first question is: Is "as well as" a preposition or conjunction here? I am inclined to say conjunction because it feels replaceable by "and" but it does lead a phrase in which it is followed by a noun phrase "questions of..."

Also the author seems to have made a conscious decision to break up a whole grammatical sentence into two separated by a period, which I have to say seems to effectively render it ungrammatical. **I understand this is a stylistic choice** and it is permissible for emphasis, among other stylistic reasons. But I think it is definitely more common in fiction writing. And I don't really see this kind of separation in nonfiction, especially academic writing. Am I right in thinking it is ungrammatical and should have been avoided?

My last question is: "seem tacitly to assume" reads really weird. I would have written "which may **seem to tacitly assume** that individuals are infinitely flexible" because the adverb "tacitly" modifies the verb "assume" not "seem". Does the original work as written and is it a syntactic/semantic problem?

Comment: I don't know why you say that "as well as" is replaceable by "and". It isn't, which indicates that "as well as questions of the form" is not coordinate but an AdvP functioning as an adjunct in which the second "as" is a preposition taking an NP complement. This analysis is reinforced by the fact that coordinators do not occur in initial position in the first coordinate in examples like yours.

Comment: What strikes me is that 'Nevertheless, it is A which offers the most hope, by bringing us into a B of C which has close connections with D. As well as questions ....' seems ambiguous.

Comment: "As well as" can mean "also," not "and" because "and" is a coordinating conjunction and affects subject-count for verb conjugation, while "as well as" doesn't, like one would say, "John and Bob *are* here," or, "John, as well as Bob, *is* here," but never, "John as well as Bob *are* here." HOWEVER, how "as well as" is used there, it doesn't mean "also" but means "in addition to," a nuance, to be sure. THAT SAID, I'm not answering your question because questions based on a false premise, like that it's one or the other when it can be both, are unanswerable under the terms of this site.

Comment: You might find what this site has to say on the subject informative: https://englishgrammarhere.com/conjunctions/using-in-addition-in-english-example-sentences-with-in-addition/#:~:text=Today%2C%20we%20will%20examine%20a,the%20beginning%20of%20a%20sentence.

Comment: The idiomatic "as well as" is ruled out as a coordinating conjunction here because of its initial position in the sentence. It is an AdvP consisting of adverb+adverb+preposition (+NP)

Comment: Very helpful comments!